# How to do argmax in group in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, scatter

Is there any ways to implement maxpooling according to norm of sub vectors in a group in Pytorch? Specifically, this is what I want to implement:

**Input**:

**x**: a 2-D float tensor, shape **#Nodes * dim**

**cluster**: a 1-D long tensor, shape **#Nodes**

**Output**:

**y**, a 2-D float tensor, and:

**y[i]=x[k] where k=argmax_{cluster[k]=i}(torch.norm(x[k],p=2))**.

I tried `torch.scatter` with `reduce="max"`, but this only works for `dim=1 and x[i]>0`.

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Please share a minimal version of the code outlining the issue so that the community can analyze it and provide suggestions.

Comment: I tried to simplify my questions and the new version is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in function to do what you want. Basically this would be some form of scatter_reduce on the norm of `x`, but instead of selecting the max norm you want to select the row corresponding to the max norm.

A straightforward implementation may look something like this

```py
"""
input
    x: float tensor of size [NODES, DIMS]
    cluster: long tensor of size [NODES]
output
    float tensor of size [cluster.max()+1, DIMS]
"""

num_clusters = cluster.max().item() + 1
y = torch.zeros((num_clusters, DIMS), dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
for cluster_id in torch.unique(cluster):
    x_cluster = x[cluster == cluster_id]
    y[cluster_id] = x_cluster[torch.argmax(torch.norm(x_cluster, dim=1), dim=0)]
```

Which should work just fine if `clusters.max()` is relatively small. If there are many clusters though then this approach has to unnecessarily create masks over `cluster` for every unique cluster id. To avoid this you can make use of `argsort`. The best I could come up with in pure python was the following.

```py
num_clusters = cluster.max().item() + 1
x_norm = torch.norm(x, dim=1)

cluster_sortidx = torch.argsort(cluster)
cluster_ids, cluster_counts = torch.unique_consecutive(cluster[cluster_sortidx], return_counts=True)

end_indices = torch.cumsum(cluster_counts, dim=0).cpu().tolist()
start_indices = [0] + end_indices[:-1]

y = torch.zeros((num_clusters, DIMS), dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
for cluster_id, a, b in zip(cluster_ids, start_indices, end_indices):
    indices = cluster_sortidx[a:b]
    y[cluster_id] = x[indices[torch.argmax(x_norm[indices], dim=0)]]
```

For example in random tests with `NODES = 60000`, `DIMS = 512`, `cluster.max()=6000` the first version takes about 620ms whie the second version takes about 78ms.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed description! That really helps.